# Only display correlation coefficient in ggplot stat_cor

Tags: r, ggplot2, pearson-correlation

How do you only display the correlation coefficient in ggpubr::stat_cor, and not the p-value? There doesn't seem to be an argument within stat_cor to specify only one statistic or the other. Is there some other creative work-around?

Comment: `ggplot2` doesn't have a `stat_cor`. Which add-on package are you using? Maybe `ggpubr`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: No, I'm using geom_point in ggplot, not ggpubr.

Comment: Echoing Gregor, there is no `ggplot2::stat_cor`; the ggplot2 package has no such function, whereas `ggpubr` does.

Comment: ok, edited. the question still remains, how do you remove the p-value from stat_cor()?

Comment: can you try including: `aes(label = ..r.label..)` in `stat_cor`? this should show only the R value. https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/188

Comment: just including ..r.label.. worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Following Ben's solution - I including a reproducible example.
First let's use a simple example:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('ggpubr')
data(iris)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width  )) +
geom_point() + theme_bw() +
stat_cor(method = "pearson")
```

[image]

Now, you wanted to display only the correlation coefficient, meaning R.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width  )) +
geom_point() + theme_bw() +
stat_cor(method = "pearson", aes(label = ..r.label..))
```

Actually you can also calculate the R-value independently, and ad a textbox in the plot using annotate(example from iris database):

```
round(cor(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width),2)
```

[image]